# AssertionError: 403 != 200 in APITestCase

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i have this url:

```
    path('post/',views.PostListCreateAPIView.as_view(),name='post_lc'),
```

with an app-name :

```
    app_name='blog_api'
```

and trying to test it like :

```
class TestPost(APITestCase):

    def test_view_posts(self):
        response = self.client.get('blog_api:post_lc')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

and even with url directly :

```
class TestPost(APITestCase):

    def test_view_posts(self):
        response = self.client.get('/api/post/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

the url and the views, are functioning works well, but the test keep giving the error

```
AssertionError: 403 != 200
```

and i just can't figure out why, thanks for the help

**Update**

i forgot that i had IsAuthenticated, which caused the 403 error

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
]}
```

Comment: 403 means that the logged in has no permission to alter this.

Comment: ok thanks to point that out i figured it out, Silly mistake,